# How do I calculate probability

Tags: probability

I have this statement, but I want to be able to add a probability statement to it, like "I'm 87% sure.."

Here is the data I have

> I'm 100.00% sure that grpn will go down the next day, because it's happened 3 of the last 3 times.
>       Min move of 0.66%
>       Max move of 16.54%
>       Avg move of 8.74%

I want to say (obviously replacing X, Y, and Z)

> I'm 100.00% sure that grpn will go down the next day, because it's happened 3 times. I'm X% sure it will move at least .66% and Y% sure it will move 8.7% and Z% sure it will move 16.5%.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to consider replacing the 100.00% too?

Comment: Sure, I can replace the 100%, what is the simple calculation for it?

Answer (score 3):

"I'm 100.00% sure that grpn will go down the next day, because it's happened 3 of the last 3 times."

Seeing something 3 out of 3 times does not mean that you know it will happen a fourth *with 100% certainty*.  Ask yourself the question - is there any way, however unlikely, that you could imagine that grpn could go up in the next day?   Could there be an announcement of a new product, or an unpopular manager gets fired, etc...  If you can, then you are not *100%* sure it will go down.  If you're just given the data:

"Min move of 0.66%
Max move of 16.54%
Avg move of 8.74%"

for the past 3 times, then you need to specify a model which summarizes the behavior.  When in doubt, the normal distribution should be used, and then you should get the actual values of the moves, not just average, min, and max.  With a proper prior, you can then calculate the probability of any value of the moves - some of the moves will be positive!  It may turn out that it is a very low probability for the move to be positive, but it will not be zero.

If, however, you have the data above and you're saying you *know* that the moves have to fall within 0.66% drop and 16.54% drop, with an average of 8.74% (which is not in the middle of the range), then you'd have to use a maximum entropy method to define the distribution.  I doubt this is your case, because I can't imagine a situation where you could know this information for certain.

Thus, you really do have to ask: what is the *actual* data I have, and what can I infer from it.  This will lead to a better question, and a more defined answer.

hope this helps!

Comment: That all sounds like what I want to hear, and yes we're weighing the data against common sense, but what statement can I make with the data I have. I really just need some simple calculations, like (a*b)+(b/c)+r = something, to plug into the reporting engine.

Answer (score 2):

reverse this. Not going down has happened 0 of 3 times. The rule of 3 states 3/n  is a good approximation for an upper 95% confidence bound for the probability of an event that hasn't occurred. (here 3/3=1, meaning you can't really rule out anything) That assumes independence and a large sample, but the dependence and small sample don't help.

With such a small sample in a domain with known volatility (stocks) you can't say much.

reference: Winkler Smith and Fryback, TAS, 2002.

Comment: I've never encountered that rule before.  Thanks for pointing it out.